# can anybody know about how to add in-app purchases to android application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am very confused with in-app purchase for an android application, and how to **add products in play store**(which type like managed,unmanaged),and how to **link those products into my application**.

In my application when we click on button i want to popup in-app to subscribe(if it's not subscribed) otherwise open the functionality of that button.

can anyone knows please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inApp purchase please follow below link care fully (do not miss any step)

1. Adding inApp-purchase  library
2. Add permission in manifest file
3. use key from play store
4. Create item id on play store and link with id in application.
5. Use signed apk for playstore.
6. After integrating inapp purchse, test with signed apk with same key.

1.http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

for tutorial :

1. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

2.http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html

Comment: Thanks, I will go through it.

Comment: where to add item id to my application, when i am clicking on the button or some where else?

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial  use this link.  And check this line static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";